# PostGIS buffer in miles not lat/long degrees

Tags: postgresql, spatial, postgis

I am trying to take two points, add a buffer around them (in meters), draw a line between them, draw a buffer around that, and then query whether items are inside the area of the circles expanded line joining them.

I have my columns in regular postgres point type, so I have to do some massaging with ST_MakePoint from the lat/long. I'm leaving out tables and columns because I think it's strictly a data-type/misunderstanding on my part.

I got the following working, but it feels like I'm doing way more than I need to:

```
SELECT ST_Intersects(
  ST_Collect(
    ARRAY[
      ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-97.791803, 30.447039), 4326), 2163), 10 * 1609.3444),
      ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-97.743119, 30.268503), 4326), 2163), 10 * 1609.3444),
      ST_Buffer(
        ST_Transform(
          ST_SetSRID(
            ST_MakeLine(
              ST_MakePoint(-97.791803, 30.447039),
              ST_MakePoint(-97.743119, 30.268503)
            ),
            4326
          ),
          2163
        ),
        10 * 1069.344, 'endcap=flat'
      )
    ]
  )::geometry,
  ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-97.791803, 30.447039), 4326), 2163)
) AS intersects;
```

I'll be honest, I'm not even sure if this makes sense in PostGIS world, or if I'm trying to do some square peg in round hole type stuff. Hopefully that's enough to show that I'm trying to solve it on my own and what "solved" looks like, in this context.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks to me like your first query matches your verbal description, while the second does not. What is that third point anyway? Your working query looks reasonable to me. Are you not happy with the performance? Do you have some other problem with it?

Comment: Thanks for replying! 

I updated to explain a little better an hopefully make it more readable.

Basically, that second query was my WIP, I edited to add the third one with the working buffer and transform. It seems like I'm doing extra steps that I don't need to, but I don't know enough to know if this is a reasonable way to go about it or not.

Comment: Perhaps a better question is, is there a better way to accomplish what I want? Drawing the line between the two and using ST_Collect and ST_Intersects seems reasonable to me, but I'm just beginning to use PostGIS.

Comment: You should use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` to benchmark both your solutions. That will show you which is faster. If the original query is fast enough, I'd just go with it.

Comment: Have you considered using GEOGRAPHY instead of GEOMETRY which would save all the reprojection?